# Criteria when targeting minimum Android API level

Tags: android

What criteria should a developer consider when choosing the minimum API level for his Android application?

According to the [dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), only 3.2% of Android devices are using an API level that's less than 17. But are those devices worth accommodating for? Who is it that won't update their Android device? Are they hobbyists or test devices that will expect incompatibility with most apps?

Comment: "Only 3.2%" is still 50+ million people. We have no way to tell you what those people are thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as a developer, you ought to decide if the number of users who would potentially download your app for those versions of Android is worth to put effort into developing the app for those versions.

Besides the distribution percentage, it depends on your target audience and the type of application you wanna create aligned with business goals.

As a matter of fact, you should take into account the [compatibility](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html) of some API features you may implement such as hardware access permissions and so on.